# Weird position taken by a div

Tags: css, position

I have a strange situation, where my middle `div` is slightly downward.
Here's a screenshot:
[image]

HTML :

```
<div id="footer">
    <div class="content">
        <div id="info1">
            <img src="img/temp.png" alt="About me" />
            <h4>About Me</h4>
            <p>this is about me section</br>and this is the other line</br>and this is a third line</p>
        </div>
        <div id="info2">                                            
            <h4>Random Photos</h4>
            <div id="randomPhotos"></div>
        </div>
        <div id="info3">
            <h3>Follow Me</h3>
            <div>
            <img src="img/temp.png" alt="facebook" /><a href="#">Facebook</a>
            </div>
            <div>
            <img src="img/temp.png" alt="twitter" /><a href="#">Twitter</a>
            </div>
            <div>
            <img src="img/temp.png" alt="email" /><a href="#">E-mail</a>
            </div>            
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#info1, #info2, #info3
{    
    padding: 10px;
    display:inline-block;
}

#info1
{
    width:20%;
}

#info1 img
{
    margin-right:3px;
    width:20px;
    height:20px;
    background-image:url('../img/glyphicons-halflings.png');
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    background-position:-162px 1px;
}

#info1 img, #info1 h4
{
    display:inline-block;
}

#info2
{
    width:55%;
    border-left:1px solid gray;
    border-right : 1px solid gray;
}
#info3
{
    width:15%;
}

#info3 img 
{
    width:20px;
    height:20px;
    margin-right:5px;
}

#info3 img[alt="facebook"]
{
    background : url('../img/result.png') no-repeat 0px -30px;    
}

#info3 img[alt="twitter"]
{
    background : url('../img/result.png') no-repeat 0px -60px;
}

#info3 img[alt="email"]
{
    background : url('../img/result.png') no-repeat 0px 0px;
}

#info2 div 
{
    padding:3px;

}

#randomPhotos 
{
    height : 100px;
}
```

I'm really not that good at CSS, so it maybe a small problem. I just can't find it out.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Most browsers, for elements using `display:inline-block` will automatically use `vertical-align:baseline` on that element unless you use a CSS reset (that will probably also define the defacto standard as `vertical-align:baseline`.)

This is the reason for what you are seeing, each one of your info divs is aligning to the baseline. As the central `div` is smaller height wise you get the gap you are seeing at the top.

To fix it:

```
#info1, #info2, #info3
{    
    padding: 10px;
    display:inline-block;
    vertical-align:top;
}
```

The second problem you will probably encounter is that now it is aligned top, you have a 'gap' at the bottom with no left or right borders. Either have the borders managed by the full height divs or make all the divs the same height.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you to add `float: left` to each of your divs. This solve your problem.

[example](http://jsfiddle.net/LGSgx/1/)

Answer (score 1):

You could also try to

```
position:absolute;
```

the divs inside the container and then specify

```
top:0px;
left: (left div with)px;
```

I am always working with absolute, hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

```
#info2
{
  vertical-align: top
}
```

should do the trick.